# Transaction is not being carried out

Tags: corda

Transaction:
[image: Screenshot]

After starting the flow, I see the word "starting", but the command gets exited before it's completed and the transaction isn't stored in the vault. Let me know what are the possible reasons for this to happen. Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you share node logs

Comment: @SnehaDamle The logs for all the nodes are empty when I checked in the build folder from IntelliJ. Is this normal??

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure the `FinalityFlow` is called.

Since your screencap is the flow initiator, then that means your implemented flow does not record the transaction into its vault.
To do that, you may want to use the FinalityFlow after collecting all the signatures. For example,

```
subFlow(new FinalityFlow(fullySignedTransaction, singletonList(session)));
```

[The sample project](https://github.com/corda/samples-java/blob/16ae2325a88a45349f7ce03072fb95885a7270be/Basic/cordapp-example/workflows-java/src/main/java/com/example/flow/ExampleFlow.java#L118) where this line comes from.

Comment: error: package com.google.common.collect does not exist
import com.google.common.collect.ImmutableSet;

Comment: Could you share the full log or share on pastebin? But this should be simply some dependency problem that you can fix in your classpath.

Comment: I've overcome this error, but I'm still facing the above issue even after adding finalityflow. The code is in the following link:
https://github.com/shanmukhipriya99/taskcordapp
Please help me out!!